# ffmpeg: UDP to RTMP stream - issues with PES/out of range/corrupted macroblock

Tags: ffmpeg, udp, rtmp

I´m trying to convert a UDP multicast transportstream video to a RTMP video stream with ffmpeg.

The stream is generated with a Teracue ENC-300 hardware encoder. The encoder sends the stream as TS/UDP packets to the multicast IP 239.252.20.100:4444.
ffmpeg can convert the stream, but only at a really low bitrate and/or with a lot of errors.

My ffmpeg command looks as follows:

```
ffmpeg -re -i udp://@239.252.20.100:4444?buffer_size=32000k 
-b:v 900k -maxrate 1000k -bufsize 32000k -f flv 
"rtmp://127.0.0.1/live/live1" -loglevel debug
```

I´ve already tried some easyer code:

```
ffmpeg -re -i udp://@239.252.20.100:4444 -f flv 
"rtmp://127.0.0.1/live/live1" -loglevel debug
```

The Teracue generates the stream with a bitrate of 1500kbps. I also tried some higher or lower bitrates. But the output of ffmpeg has only a maximum bitrate of about 400kbps. If I increase the bitrate with

```
-b:v 900k
```

or sometimes, when no output bitrate is set, I get a lot of error messages, especially

```
PES packet size mismatch
error while decoding MB X X
corrupted macroblock X X
```

Here is the error code:

```
>[h264 @ 000002883adfe800] nal_unit_type: 6(SEI), nal_ref_idc: 0

>[h264 @ 000002883adfe800] nal_unit_type: 1(Coded slice of a non-IDR picture), >nal_ref_idc: 3

>[h264 @ 000002883adfe800] ct_type:1 pic_struct:0

>[mpegts @ 000002883a329340] Continuity check failed for pid 192 expected 4 >got 7

>[mpegts @ 000002883a329340] pid=c0 pes_code=0x1c0

>    Last message repeated 1 times

>[mpegts @ 000002883a329340] pid=2c pes_code=0x1e0

>[NULL @ 000002883a33f7c0] ct_type:1 pic_struct:0

>udp://@239.252.20.100:4444?buffer_size=32000k: corrupt decoded frame in 

>stream 1

>[h264 @ 000002883a35a240] nal_unit_type: 9(AUD), nal_ref_idc: 0

>[h264 @ 000002883a35a240] nal_unit_type: 6(SEI), nal_ref_idc: 0

>[h264 @ 000002883a35a240] nal_unit_type: 1(Coded slice of a non-IDR picture), 

>nal_ref_idc: 3

>[h264 @ 000002883a35a240] ct_type:1 pic_struct:0

>[h264 @ 000002883a35a240] out of range intra chroma pred mode

>[h264 @ 000002883a35a240] error while decoding MB 14 8

>[mpegts @ 000002883a329340] Continuity check failed for pid 44 expected 2 got 
>9

>[mpegts @ 000002883a329340] PES packet size mismatch

>[mpegts @ 000002883a329340] pid=2c pes_code=0x1e0

>[NULL @ 000002883a33f7c0] ct_type:1 pic_struct:0

>[h264 @ 000002883a35a240] concealing 845 DC, 845 AC, 845 MV errors in P frame

>[h264 @ 000002883a38f6c0] nal_unit_type: 9(AUD), nal_ref_idc: 0

>[h264 @ 000002883a38f6c0] nal_unit_type: 6(SEI), nal_ref_idc: 0

>[h264 @ 000002883a38f6c0] nal_unit_type: 1(Coded slice of a non-IDR picture), >nal_ref_idc: 3

>[h264 @ 000002883a38f6c0] ct_type:1 pic_struct:0

>[h264 @ 000002883a38f6c0] Frame num gap 28 26

>[mpegts @ 000002883a329340] Continuity check failed for pid 192 expected 9 >got 12

>[mpegts @ 000002883a329340] pid=c0 pes_code=0x1c0

>[mpegts @ 000002883a329340] Continuity check failed for pid 44 expected 1 got >15

>[mpegts @ 000002883a329340] PES packet size mismatch

>[mpegts @ 000002883a329340] pid=2c pes_code=0x1e0

>[NULL @ 000002883a33f7c0] ct_type:1 pic_struct:0

>udp://@239.252.20.100:4444?buffer_size=32000k: corrupt decoded frame in 
>stream 1

>[h264 @ 000002883adf1980] nal_unit_type: 9(AUD), nal_ref_idc: 0

>[h264 @ 000002883adf1980] nal_unit_type: 6(SEI), nal_ref_idc: 0

>[h264 @ 000002883adf1980] nal_unit_type: 1(Coded slice of a non-IDR picture), 

>nal_ref_idc: 3

>[h264 @ 000002883adf1980] ct_type:1 pic_struct:0

>[h264 @ 000002883adf1980] mb_type 41 in P slice too large at 18 9

>[h264 @ 000002883adf1980] error while decoding MB 18 9

>[h264 @ 000002883adf1980] concealing 796 DC, 796 AC, 796 MV errors in P frame

>[mpegts @ 000002883a329340] pid=c0 pes_code=0x1c0

>[NULL @ 000002883a33f7c0] ct_type:1 pic_struct:0

>[h264 @ 000002883adf20c0] nal_unit_type: 9(AUD), nal_ref_idc: 0

>[h264 @ 000002883adf20c0] nal_unit_type: 7(SPS), nal_ref_idc: 3

>[h264 @ 000002883adf20c0] nal_unit_type: 8(PPS), nal_ref_idc: 3

>[h264 @ 000002883adf20c0] nal_unit_type: 6(SEI), nal_ref_idc: 0

>[h264 @ 000002883adf20c0] nal_unit_type: 5(IDR), nal_ref_idc: 3

>[h264 @ 000002883adf20c0] ct_type:1 pic_struct:0

>[h264 @ 000002883adf20c0] corrupted macroblock 3 0 (total_coeff=-1) 

>114.0kbits/s speed=   1x

>[h264 @ 000002883adf20c0] error while decoding MB 3 0

>[mpegts @ 000002883a329340] pid=c0 pes_code=0x1c0
```

Any solutions?